# The edit distance of BWT of two strings with one difference

Tags: coding-theory, string-matching

Let $BWT$ stand for the [Burrows-Wheeler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform) on strings.
What is the maximal edit distance of $BWT(w)$ and $BWT(u)$, if $w$ and $u$ differ only in one character.

Comment: What have you tried?  As the [help/on-topic] says: "You should only post questions you're actually seriously thinking about. Users are expected to do their part and try to answer their question by themselves before posting them on cstheory and asking for help from others. [...]"  What's the largest edit distance you've been able to find so far?  Have you tried working through small examples with aid of a computer program?